# 30.3.2 Using Source-Level Metadata (Java annotations)

Tags: spring, jmx

The spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html) example under 30.3.2 Using Source-Level Metadata (Java annotations) shows the example implement an interface:

```
public class AnnotationTestBean implements IJmxTestBean
```

Since we are using source-level metadata to expose the methods to JMX, the interface is obsolete. The interface implementation method is described in 30.3.5 .

The documentation states that there are 3 ways to define management interfaces for the beans:

- The default implementation that exposes all public properties and methods.
- Using Source-Level Metadata (Java annotations) (30.3.2)
- Defining management interfaces using Java interfaces (30.3.5)

Am I reading this properly or is there an actual need for the interface implementation even for the source level metadata strategy?

Comment: The interface is just an interface it isn't related to JMX.

Comment: IJmxTestBean defines the methods and properties that will be exposed as operations and attributes on the JMX MBean. It's needed if "Defining management interfaces using Java interfaces (30.3.5)" method is being used but has no function when "Using Source-Level Metadata (Java annotations) (30.3.2)" is being used.

Comment: But that line isn't relevant for the earlier sections. The interface is there because that is a common programming practice, program to interfaces. Define a contract. You could use this interface to expose properties and methods to JMX or use a special interface for that. But as stated for the section you mention it is just an interface nothing more nothing less. It is all about the context.